# Algorithm : Find contour from lines in 3D

Tags: algorithm, 3d, contour

Sorry for my bad english.

I want to draw the contour of the geometric objects in 3D.

I have a set of lines defined by two points in 3D :
Line1 : P1(x1, y1, z1), P2(x2, y2, z2)
Line2 : P1(x3, y3, z3), P2(x4, y4, z4)
...
LineN : Pn, P(n + 1)
Each line is an edge of a geometric object : tetrahedron, cube, ...

Do you know if there is an algorithm that can say : LineX is part of the contour.
Or do you know an algorithm that compute the contour based on lines or points in 3D ?

NB : I found some interesting thing with convex/concave hull and alpha shape. But it's too damn complicated for me. So if you have some existing implementations, it will be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For two dimensions, if the lines define a convex polygon, the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) polygon of the vertices can be determined using a [convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), where the [Jarvis march](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) and the [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) algorithm are well-known techiques. If the polygons are not convex, it's a bit difficult to determine what the desired result is.

In three dimentsions, at least for convex bodies, I could imagine that a modification of the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) via [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the vertices could be used to find all edges of the convex hull; but the implementation would not be totally straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
The scene can be convex or concave.  
Do you have any name of algorithm which works in 3D for convex/concave scene ? I need to plot the contour of my scene.